# How to loop through a list inside of a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have two lists, a **Header list** and a **Client list**:

- **Header list** contains headers such as `First Name` or `Phone Number`.
- **Client list** contains the details for a particular client such as their first name or phone number.

I'm trying to print one piece of each list at a time.

For example:

```
First Name: Joe
Phone Number: 911
```

Right now I have a loop that does something close to what I desire

```
header_list = ['First Name: ',
               'Last Name: ',
               'Phone: ',
               'City: ',
               'State: ',
               'Zip: ']

for elem in header_list: 
    print(elem)

    for client in client_list[0]:
       print (client)
       break
```

This gives output like

```
First Name: Joe
Last Name: Joe
Phone Number: Joe
```

The problem with this loop is that it prints out all the headers correctly but only prints off the first item in `client_list[0]`, if I remove the break then it prints out everything in `client_list[0]`.

How would I loop through `client_list[0]` getting the first then the second etc on through the list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can iterate over the header and value at the same time with `zip`:

```
header_list = ['First Name: ', 'Last Name: ', 'Phone: ', 'City: ', 'State: ', 'Zip: ']
client_list = ['Joe', 'Somebody', '911']

for head, entry in zip(header_list, client_list):
    print(head, entry)
```

output:

```
First Name:  Joe
Last Name:  Somebody
Phone:  911
```

**Note**:  The shorter list determines how many iterations you get.

Longer client list:

```
header_list = ['First Name:', 'Last Name:', 'Phone:', 'City:', 'State:', 'Zip:']
client_list = ['Joe', 'Somebody', '911', 'Somewhere', 'AA', '012345']

for head, entry in zip(header_list, client_list):
    print(head, entry)
```

prints:

```
First Name: Joe
Last Name: Somebody
Phone: 911
City: Somewhere
State: AA
Zip: 012345
```

Side note: No need to pad your strings in `header` with space, `print` will add one for you.

Comment: This gave exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much, wasn't aware of zip!

Comment: Good to hear. You can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `client_list` is a list of lists, then? Would something like this work?

```
    header_list = ['name', 'number']
    client_list = [['joe', '415'], ['lara', '123']]


    for client in client_list:
        for elem in zip(header_list, client):
            print ":".join(elem)
```